# Which is correct?

Tags: grammar

"You, my peer, who know no more than I"
or
"You, my peer, who knows no more than I"

I am leaning toward the first one, but the second one sounds more natural. Which one should I choose?

Comment: Could this question be better suited for English SE?

Comment: @Alexander I agree, we just need one more close vote and it'll get migrated there.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, actually.
"You" with "know" should be the correct usage, but it still feels kind of awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging a few things could get rid of this problem. What if you switched it to "You, my peer, know no more than I" instead of "You, my peer, **who** know no more than I"? That would be going with the words from Option 1 without it sounding weird because you would be dropping the "who." You could also do, "My peer, you know no more than I", or "You know no more than I, my peer."

If you drop the "my peer" interjection, you get what you're really trying to say, which is, "You who know no more than I" and that sounds weird to me. I think "You know no more than I" makes a lot more sense. Option 2 is off here because you wouldn't say "You knows no more than I" (Grammarly even underlined it for me).

If you want the same structure, I do see why Option 2 would sound clearer because "knows" as opposed to "know" goes with "my peer". That's why moving the "my peer" could probably help. Maybe ask some friends to read it and get their opinions.

Good question by the way. Hope this wasn't just more confusing for you :)